# Combining javascript and storing output to xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to pull out dynamically generated table data from a URL.
From first web page I need to find out the dynamically linked web page where original table is located and need to fetch from there.

Here is what I have tried..

**Step I**

```
javascript: (function() {
    var source = document.getElementById("winrelinfo_iframe").src;
    window.open(source)
}())
```

**Step II**

```
javascript: (function() {
    var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
        var cellLength = oCells.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++) {
            document.write(oCells.item(j).innerHTML);
        }
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}())
```

*Step I : fetch URL of original table*
*Step II: read table and display in grid format*

*where I need help is..*

## 1. Combining both script

## 2. is it possible to store the table data to a XML?

I would like to thank in advance :)

Comment: why don't you simply invoke one method from another?

Comment: First step is to be done on one URL and step two is in another..something like parent child...